# Merging observations which occur at the same time into one observation

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
loan  client  time      interest   loan amount   country    
1       1      w          0.1       500.000        USA            
2       1      x          0.2       250.000        Germany               
3       2      y          0.1       300.000        France                 
4       2      y          0.15      400.000        France                
5       2      y          0.2       100.000        France            
6       3      z          0.1        50.000        England            
.       .      .           .           .               .
.       .      .           .           .               .
```

I observe different clients at different point in times. For some observations I observe the same client at the same time receiving 2 different loans (in this example observing client 2 at time y 3 times). I want to bundle these observations together meaning that I want to replace loans "3", "4" & "5" with one observation "3", summing the loan amount, averaging the interest rate and using the entries for all other variables from observation "3". I am wondering how I can perform these operations using Stata.

Comment: You can `collapse` to sums and means, or -- given that you seem to want the same data structure -- you can use `egen` to get new variables.

Comment: Using the collapse command seems to work well on the variables I want to sum / average out. This being said, Im unsure how I can carry forward non numeric entries. Would I have to separately  merge the collapsed dataset and the original one?

Comment: Show us an example of other variables and what you want done.

Comment: I just added another row to the example dataset. I have categorical variables which are usually identical for a client time pair. Hence I would be happy to have for my new loan "3" only the entry France which can be taken from either loan 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: I figured out how to also transfer categorical variables. I can use the "firstnm" stat to use the first non missing entry.

Comment: So, it seems that you have identified what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
collapse (mean) interest (sum) loanamount (firstnm) country, by (client time)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).